# android paging feature implementation

Tags: android, paging, implementation

I am working on a software where I would like to implement the paging feature.
I have a book via web service in json.

But is there any best practice how to calculate the current content what I can place on the current page ?
I am trying to get the row height from before it is draw but It looks a bit complicated for me.

```
 TextView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener() {
      etc ... get the height
 }
```

or is there any third api what I can use for the caluclation ? 
Thanks for your help and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use view pager:

Try dynamically creating Fragments array after reading the response from json, i.e number of pages of data you are getting. Eg

If your JSON response looks like this:

```
page:
[  
{ "pageno":1,
   "data" :..
},...]
```

**after Parsing:**

ArrayList pageList=new ArrayList<>(**Number of Pages Of data received **);

Put pageList Array into View Page adapter which will take care of paging.

I hope this answers you question.